# Why does my navbar with a position of "fixed" appear , disappear and appear again? (more explanation in the description)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm making a profile website and I've come across a issue.

So, I'm making some simple loading animations with React useState, setTimeout() and dynamic styling.

For example, If I want to show a loading page first (with a logo appearing and disappearing) and then show my main page for my portfolio, I would do something like this:

```
const [pageLoading, setPageLoading] = useState(true)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setPageLoading(false)
        }, 4500)
    }, [])
    
    // Icon load while page is loading
    const [iconLoading, setIconLoading] = useState(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIconLoading(true)
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIconLoading(false)
        }, 3000)
    }, [])

return (
  {
    pageLoading
    ?
    <div>
      // Loading page content
    </div>
    :
    <div>
     // This is where main content will go, with all of the react components
    <Header />
    <Body />
    <div>
)
```

So, when the page first loads, it will show a loading page with a logo image loading (appear -> disappear). I didn't add the css but it will change the opacity from 0% -> 100% with a transition of ?ms. After this, it will load a blank page with the Header and Body component appearing one by one. (Same logic applied to these components as with the ones above). However, the problem occurs when I apply the style of position fixed on my Header component.

When it's the Header component's turn to appear, it appears alright, but it suddenly disappears and appears again. If I don't use position fixed, this doesn't happens. It will only appear and that's it. Here's a sample code of the Header and Body components.

Here's also a link to a video that will show the problem in action: [Video link](https://youtu.be/xH_hkHUzo6o) (You will see that the Header component appears, then disappear again. I only want the Header component to appear and that's it)

```js
// Header.jsx
const [headerLoading, setHeaderLoading] = useState(false)
    
useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
    setHeaderLoading(true)
}, 500)
}, [])
    
return (
  <div className={headerLoading ? "header-loading headerLoaded" : "header-loading"}>
  ...
```

```css
.header-loading {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #062C30;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I fixed it using position sticky and setting the parent element(div) of the Header Component from a height: 100vh to min-height :100vh.

Comment: Still don't know why position:fixed doesn't work...